# Can't output image field URL in custom post type loop

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

First time building a Wordpress site. Having some trouble wrapping my head around the essential concepts for iterating through posts of a particular post type and retrieving data values.

Posting this question also because I couldn't find any comparable issues.

```
<?php
    $gallery_args = array('post_type' => 'gallery');
    $gallery_array = get_posts( $gallery_args );
    foreach ( $gallery_array as $image ) : setup_postdata( $image );
?>
    <img src="<?php echo the_field( "image_upload"); ?>"/>
<?php
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This is what I have. The for-loop works as proven by the fact that I see the containing elements of the image being repeated. However, when it gets to the  tag, this is the output: `<img src>`.

I'm using the ACF plugin if that helps at all.

**EDIT**

Also read that `the_field()` prints the value directly. But it doesn't output even without the preceding `echo` you see in my above code. Also tried `echo get_field()`.

Comment: What type of ACF field is "image_upload" (e.g. is it an "Image" field type or "File" field type or something else)?

Comment: It's an image field type. With a URL return value @Kory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your call to `get_posts()` was grabbing the `$post` data for the page you were running the code on and *not* the "Gallery" custom post type. I'm not sure why that is, but I got the query to run properly by using [wp_query()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instead of `get_posts()`

The code is quite similar, but looks like this:

```
<?php 
    $gallery_args = array('post_type' => 'gallery');
    $gallery_array = new WP_Query( $gallery_args ); 
    while ( $gallery_array->have_posts() ) : $gallery_array->the_post(); 
?>
        <img src="<?php the_field("image_upload"); ?>" />
<?php 
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data
?>
```

Comment: Ahh perfect! Thank you so much